# Is it possible to make a tor browser

Tags: windows

Ive had this idea for some time, in which I want to make a TOR browser, or just an onion browser.However,  I cannot find any good information online. If you are able to make your own onion browser, can somebody how to? I know how a a onion browser works, and advanced programming knowledge.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? If you only want to be able to access onion services in the browser, you can just edit your tor configuration for Tor Browser and add the `OnionTrafficOnly` option.

Comment: I also want clarification. You claim to have “advanced programming knowledge”. Surely you realise that the source code of Tor Browser is publicly available. Have you tried looking at it?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I can suggest is to use socks5 proxy in your browser. Let me explain.
Passing traffic (of any program including browser) through tor is possible by sending it through tor's socks5 proxy. Therefore, your browser should be able to use socks5 proxy which is opened by running tor.

Additionally your browser should resolve domain names (whether normal domains or onions) through socks5. Suggest you to check firefox's proxy settings. These settings are working to change a normal firefox to onion browsing firefox.

[image: Tor Socks5 settings]

But there are other feature included in Tor Browser. For instance, NoScript addon for preventing execution of java script in web pages or https everywhere for using https version of the web pages. Hope it helped.